# Maximum number of disks and amount of storage support by Ubuntu OS?

Tags: ubuntu, storage, amazon-web-services

We are using AWS ec2 instances and we want to attach EBS volumes to EC2 instances using a program.

In order to over burden one particular EC2 instance by attaching more storage than it can handle, I would like to know how many hard disks (e.g. 5 hard disks) and storage size (e.g. 32 TB or 1 PB, etc.) is supported by Ubuntu.

Thanks,
Chandrashekhar

Comment: Why do you want to overburden it? Please refer to [What is the largest hard drive (in gigabytes) that Ubuntu Linux will support?](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/13027). I think it will depend upon hardware limits and not OS limits.

Comment: Cross posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164431/how-many-hard-disks-and-storage-size-is-supported-by-ubuntu?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

The SCSI host adapter typically supports either 256 maximum disks. The storage limitations are going to be due to the filesystem you've chosen rather than the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using 64-bit hardware only and you have a technically unlimited hardware configuration, a 64-bit ext4 (not ext3) filesystem will be able to hold a maximum of 1 EiB. However, you are unlikely to have a drive that size, so instead it could be achieved using a RAID configuration.

If you are looking for linux kernel limits, there are virtually no limits. When you run out of /dev/sd*, it just continues to /dev/sd**, and will continue to add possibilities.

So in software terms, there is no practically reachable limit, however please note that it will become extremely difficult to manage that many drives.